# Can I use a 360 controller on Xbox one

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-one

Since Windows 10 came out I have been enjoying the stream xbox games to PC feature, I use the wireless adapter for 360 with a 360 controller on my PC and all the Xbox One games I have tried work so far.

My question is has anyone tried using the 360 controller on xbox one with the wireless adapter or some other device?

Comment: just wondering if anyone had done it ...

Answer (score 2):

The Xbox One console is not directly compatible with Xbox 360 controllers.

However; as you have experienced, Windows 10 will still register Xbox 360 controllers, for the purpose of Xbox One streaming.

I have a USB Xbox 360 controller that can not directly connect to my console, but works perfectly fine when streaming to my PC.

As it appears, OP has attempted the same with the wireless converter, with no luck.